# overlaid plots using different axes in R

Tags: r, plot, overlay, axis, axes

I am trying to overlay two graphs onto the same axes.  I set up my axes limits and labels first, but then when I plot the graphs they resize and are not on my pre-determined scale.

I have pared my code down into a simple example.  You can see that 100 and 10 are showing up at the same place on the y axis.  Please help!

```
x<- 1:3
y1<- c(100, 75, 20)
y2<- c(10, 9, 4)

plot.new()                              
plot(0, type="n",    
     xlim=c(1,max(x)), ylim=c(0,max(y1,y2)),
     xlab= "x label", ylab= "y label", main= "This stupid graph doesn't work!")
par(new=TRUE)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x,y1, type="b", pch=19, col="orchid", 
     axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x,y2, type="b", pch=19, col="slateblue", 
     axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)
legend("topright",c("This is","Annoying"), col=c("orchid","slateblue"), pch=19)
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to plot twice and not use lines()? 

For example: 

lines(x, y1, type = "b", pch = 19, col = "orchid")
lines(x, y2, type="b", pch=19, col="slateblue")

Comment: Yes because in my more complicated actual data I am 1. generating and plotting the data in a For loop, and 2. the points and lines are color coded differently so they need to be plotted separately to be the right color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `lines` to add the second line, meanwhile making sure that `ylim` allows for all the values being plotted to fit within the plotting region.

```
plot(y1 ~ x, ylim = range(c(y1, y2)), xlab = "x label", ylab = "y label",
       main = "This one might work!", type = 'b', pch = 19, col = "orchid")
lines(y2, type = 'b', pch = 19, col = 'slateblue')
legend("topright", c("R is", "awesome"), col = c("orchid","slateblue"), pch = 19)
```

[image]

Comment: This works but can you please explain why?  I don't understand the difference between using `plot()` and using `points()` or `lines()`.  I thought `lines()` was just a shortcut to saying `plot(..., type="l")`, but clearly there is a more meaningful difference between the two functions.  Thanks!

Comment: plot() creates a piece of paper for you to draw on, and the functions like lines() or points() allow you to draw on that piece of paper. If you are doing simple plots, you can do all this in one go with the plot function. But as plots become more complex, functions like lines and points give you more control over what your plot looks like. You also might like to look into packages such as ggplot or lattice as plots start getting really complex.